# Possible to "hide" number of available CPUs from a process?

Tags: linux, boot, grub

I have a Linux binary that crashes if it sees more than n number of CPUs in the system. I can get it to run if I boot using the "maxcpus" kernel parameter and restrict the number of visible CPUs, but I'd rather have some way of restricting the number of CPUs on a per-process basis. Is this possible in Linux? I'm running kernel 5.19.

**UPDATE:**

I figured out a way to it without the kernel parameter. You can just write zeros to /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX for the CPUs you want to disable. Here's a shell script that will do it:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Disable CPUs 8-15 on a 16 core machine:
for i in {8..15};
do echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu${i}/online
done
```

I know this isn't technically on a per-process basis, but at least the CPUs can be enabled/disabled while the system is running without having to reboot. This works for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to try to use the Linux `taskset` command to run your process. There are other ways, but this is the one you are looking for.

Look at the command line options for [taskset](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/taskset.1.html) .. and specifically, the `-c` parameter where you can specify which specific CPUs you want the process to be able to access.

Example:
I want to let `numnutz` run on cores 0, 2, and 3
`$ taskset -c 0,2,3 numnutz`

This will probably solve your dilemma.  Please let me know if it does. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, taskset doesn't hide the total number of CPUs from the process. If I grab the value of sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN) in a C program, it still reports the number of CPUs as 16. :(